# Salesforce Community: Send event from window to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, locker-service, gtm

I'm working on the LWC that sends an event to Google Tag Manager via `window.dataLayer.push()`.

I have the Lightning Locker service enabled, so I cannot access the window property fully.

I can push to `dataLayer` via the `CustomEvent` though:

```
const pushToDataLayer = new CustomEvent('pushToDataLayer', {
    detail: {
        ...
    },
    bubbles: true,
    composed: true
});
this.dispatchEvent(pushToDataLayer);
```

It works just fine.

The task that I try to accomplish is to register a callback. The goal is

- Push an event to `dataLayer` from the LWC
- Get the response from Google
- Do something in the LWC based on that response

Is there a way to achieve that?

Could we send a `CustomEvent` down to the LWC? Could we invoke Apex from the window (custom JS in the `<head>` section)? Rest API? EMP API?

I ran out of ideas :( Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using Lightning Message Service (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel).

```
connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        const messageContext = createMessageContext();
        publish(messageContext, messageChannel, event.data);
        releaseMessageContext(messageContext);
    });
        
    this.messageChannelSubscription = subscribe(
       this.messageContext,
       messageChannel,
       (message) => this.handleMessage(message));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The last time I had a call with SF, there was a limitation on cross-component usage of LMS inside Communities (LEX).

I completely forgot about my question, but as it turns out, you can send CustomEvents back to LWC. It works with enabled Lightning Locker Service. If you have `bubbles: true` you can listen for the event in child LWC.

Comment: Ah, so you wanted to send an event from the parent's window context to the child LWC, right? I thought you meant switching context from window to class within the same LWC component.